# Standard OS for Raspberry PI 3

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have been out of the Raspberry Pi game for a while now, since 2012. I have just purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 to add to my collection. I was wondering if Debian Linux is still the go to LWDE for such boards of if something new has become the standard OS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This isn't the place for this question. As Raspberry Pis run Linux, you should probably ask this on [Unix/Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Raspberry Pi is on topic here (although there is a dedicated site with 400X the subject followers; hover on the tag).  However, this particular question is likely to be seen as a request for either a software recommendation or opinion, both of which are off-topic here.  It's also likely to attract a list, with people taking it as a poll and suggesting what they use, which tends to be considered too broad.  I'm having trouble figuring out how you can ask what you want to know in an on-topic way.

Answer (score 2):

Although partially opinion-based, you are partially correct that Debian is still the "default" distro/OS for the Raspberry Pi.

The Raspberry Pi Foundation has their own Debian-based distro called Raspbian. The download for that can be found on their [site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).